# Please identify bird call / animal call

Tags: species-identification, ornithology, bioacoustics

What species is making this sound?

You can hear it from the opening samples of this song: [Earthgarden by Nada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC3XZEWB5GM) (2003).

I wish to study the frequency distribution of the bird call.

Comment: just to know the species of bird in the sample. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a Curlew (*Numenius arquata*).

- http://www.british-birdsongs.uk/curlew/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7V25M0szqU

Comment: Awesome knowledge there. it may not be the precise same bird but it is very close and it may be, unless someone has a better idea, we can say it's as good as same bird.